# Random variation inside NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, random, simulation

I am using `NMaximize` as following code.

```
NMinimize[{x[1] + x[1]^RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 30]] + 
x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3]] x[5], 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3]]*x[1] + x[2] > 3 && 
x[3] > 1 && x[4] > 0 && x[5] > 0 && x[1] <= 1 && x[2] <= 8 && 
x[3] <= 1 && x[4] <= 1 && x[5] <= 2}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], 
x[5]}]
```

I want to variate random variables for 100 times and capture the optimized data including the maximized function values and all variables for each time.What will be the best way to capture them? of course the situation there is no answer and also unboundedness have to be taken into the account.

Comment: In your problem, at a max., one *always* has `x[1] == x[3] == x[4] == 1`; and `x[2] == 8` or there is no max (according as the `RandomVariate` is > -1 or not).  The only really interesting behavior is for `x[5]`, provided the `RandomVariate` is less than `0.255639`, which happens for less than 6% of the variates.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That isn't fair. Thinking should be avoided in this kind of problems

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was joking ... :)

Comment: @belisarius I edited the code .Actually I didn't want a lot agitation in this cause now there are many cases of unboundedness and .......Can we also capture them and show?

Comment: Thanks guys!I got my answer.The only problem is how to catch for example "unboundedness" when the problem is not achieving the result or not converging after certain iteration numbers?is there any way for it?Anyhow I have got what I wanted.thanks and sorry for no skill in programming.

Comment: Not really, no. A numerical minimizer can prove (in some sense) that there exists a minimum by finding it. It cannot prove that one does not exist. For that you need a different approach. By the way, please delete your obsolete comments yourself rather than making one of our moderators do it for you.

Comment: @OleksandrR.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
NMaximize[{x[1] + x[1]^2 + #[[1]] x[2] + 2 Sin[Sin[x[3]]] + x[4] + 
     Sin[Sin[x[5]]] + Sin[x[1]] + x[2] + Sin[x[3]] + 
     x[4] + #[[2]] x[5], 
    x[1] > 0 && x[2] > 3 && x[3] > 1 && x[4] > 0 && x[5] > 0 && 
     x[1] <= 1 && x[2] <= 8 && x[3] <= 1 && x[4] <= 1 && 
     x[5] <= 2}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}] & /@ 
 Transpose@{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 30], 10], 
            RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3],  10]}

(*
{{81.9943, {x[1] -> 1., x[2] -> 8., x[3] -> 1., x[4] -> 1., x[5] -> 2.}},  
 {54.3253, {x[1] -> 1., x[2] -> 8., x[3] -> 1., x[4] -> 1., x[5] -> 1.41357}}, 
 {19.4185, {x[1] -> 1., x[2] -> 3., x[3] -> 1., x[4] -> 1., x[5] -> 2.}}, 
  .....
*)
```

Comment: thanks.yes thats what I want actually regardless of how the answers going to behave.